# Print recursion steps

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, printing

I would like to print the steps my program made and put these steps in a list. But i can't figure out why my code prints the wrong output. I am new to programming and i hope somoene could help. This is my code:

```
r=[]
listOfsteps = []
j = 0

class Main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        i=0
        while i != 1:
            self.method(r, j)
            i+=1

    def method(self, r, j):

        r.append(j)
        listOfsteps.append(r)
        j+=1
        if j ==5:
            return "stop"
        print r
        print "ListOfSteps", listOfsteps
        return self.method(r, j)

Main()
```

Output now:

```
[0]
ListOfSteps [[0]]
[0, 1]
ListOfSteps [[0, 1], [0, 1]]
[0, 1, 2]
ListOfSteps [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
ListOfSteps [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Output that I want:

```
[0]
ListOfSteps [[0]]
[0, 1]
ListOfSteps [[0], [0, 1]]
[0, 1, 2]
ListOfSteps [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
ListOfSteps [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: `listOfsteps` is a list containing serveral referenes to *the same r* list. So when you modfy `r`, every element of `listOfsteps` is updated, because they are all the same list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
listOfsteps.append(list(r))
```

Instead of:

```
listOfsteps.append(r)
```

in your version you append a reference to `r` and in the next iteration you change `r` so the reference you have stored is affected. You need to copy a list you want to append.

You could also use **[`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)** for doing this.

Comment: @L.B If Pawel's answer answered your question, mark it as accepted so other users that might face a similar problem will know what worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
r=[]
listOfsteps = []
j = 0

class Main(object): 

 def __init__(self):
       #you don't need loop while for your example 
        self.method(r, j)

    def method(self, r, j):

        r.append(j)
        # append only the steps index
        #you don't need to add whole list for every step
        listOfsteps.append(j)
        j+=1
        if j == 5:
            return "stop"
        print r
        #to print your step with your output that you want use this loop
        l = [listOfsteps[:i+1] for i in range(len(listOfsteps))]
        print "ListOfSteps", l

        return self.method(r, j)

Main()
```

Comment: You just incorporated the other answer in yours without a single explanation of why and how it works. Please fix your answer a bit, it is of low quality right now.

Comment: I'm new in stackoverflow it's my fist answer, thanks a lot for your advice :)